# How to add values, that are stored in an array, as textContent or innerText to div elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, queryselector

I want the values stored in the array added to the div elements with className .score. There are 12 elements and 12 values. Example first element: `<div class="score">15<div>` and so on.
The code I tried adds the last value of the array to all of the elements, that ofcourse is not what I want. Thanks.

```
var nums = [15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 28, 28];

function addValue() {
   var e = document.querySelectorAll('.score')
   Array.from(e).forEach(el => {
      for (let value of nums) {
         el.textContent = value
      }
   })
}

addValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the second parameter to `forEach`, the index you're iterating over, to identify which element in `nums` to set:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.score').forEach((el, i) => {
  el.textContent = nums[i];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the second parameter of the `forEach` loop (which is the index of the array) to get the value of the `nums` array, as the both arrays are of same length.

> Note that the element array return by `document.querySelectorAll` is by default iterable. You don't need to use `Array.from`.

**Example:**

```js
(function() {
    var nums = [15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 28, 28];

    function addValue() {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll('.score')
        e.forEach((el, index) => {
            el.textContent = nums[index]
        });
    }
    addValue();
})()
```

```html
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
```

Or you could use `Array.from` callback method to populate the divs.

**Example:**

```js
(function() {
    var nums = [15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 28, 28];

    function addValue() {
        Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll('.score'),
            (el, index) => el.textContent = nums[index]
        );
    }
    addValue();
})()
```

```html
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a classic for loop,

```js
var nums = [15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 28, 28];
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('.score');
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  arr[i].textContent = nums[i];
}
```

```html
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
<div class="score"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to loop through the nums array and for each number, create a new div, set its text content, and append the new div to a scores wrapper array.

Then you don't need to know in advance how many divs to hardcode in your html. You can simply just add an item to the array, and boom. Your html updates automatically.

Note: As the loop iterates, you use `i` to move through the array. So as `i` increases in value, you are moving from left to right in the array. So `i` starts at `0` and goes until the last index position of the array inclusive.

Note: it doesn't need to be a classic for loop. You can use forEach and other built-in methods that loop. If you use forEach, use the second argument in the parameter list to access the index.

```js
const nums = [15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 28, 28];
const scoresWrapper = document.getElementById('scoresWrapper');
for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.textContent = nums[i];
    scoresWrapper.append(newDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="scoresWrapper"></div>
```